# Using the plural of "antenna" in figurative sense

Tags: vocabulary, plural-forms, headlinese

> PBS Scrutiny Raises Political Antennas
>
> http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/articles/A8067-2005Apr21.html

Yes, this is a headline, so may be that it is not entirely representative of "standard" English speech, but the use of the word *antennas* makes me down because I have always thought that when English speakers use the plural of *antenna* in a figurative political or social sense they have to write/say *antennae*.

Can anybody clarify what the correct usage is in cases like the above?

Comment: "Antennas" is certainly not standard, but given the language creep that English experiences, I'm not particularly surprised to see it. Saddened and repulsed, yes, but not surprised

Comment: "**Headline English**" (not "title" English) follows its own rules. Regular plurals are easier to remember than irregular plurals. Who studies Latin these days? Textspeak's the lingua franca of the young & the restless. Latin's even older than my old man! Like B&W silent movies. Even biblical fundamentalists believe their bible was written in dumbed-down English & "foreign tongues" are "evil". See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_English_Bible_translations) & [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Word_on_the_Street_(book). "First off, nothing." Then culture. Now, "nothing much".

Comment: Most native English speakers are really bad at pluralising words derived from Latin and Greek. Don't always assume that us natives know what we're doing!! :-)

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with Jonathan Garber's comment that "antennas" is "certainly not standard".  I would draw the same distinction [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/antenna) does:

- The plural of "antenna" in technical contexts, as when talking about an antenna on a radio, is usually "antennas".
- The plural of "antenna" in biological contexts, as when talking about the antennae on an ant, is almost always "antennae".

In general and historically, "antennae" is more common, and I would only think it was mildly strange to hear "radio antennae".  Note that [other](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/antenna) [dictionaries](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/antenna) draw the same distinction.

*In this example*, you could say that "antennae" is more appropriate because it metaphorically fits the biological context, not the technical context, but "antennas" is certainly part of standard English.

Comment: I agree. Satellite dishes, radio receivers, radar etc are "antennas" and ants have "antennae". Another one of those fun inconsistencies to confuse the learner.

Comment: [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/antenna) appears to agree with other dictionaries mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 6):

The correct plural form is indeed *antennae*, but a lot of words with unusual plural forms are often incorrectly pluralized with 's'es.  So the writer is not correct, but likely doesn't know that.

A few more examples of words with non-standard plural forms which people will sometimes pluralize incorrectly with 's' or 'es', selected from a list [here](http://www.prdaily.com/Main/Articles/39_plural_forms_that_might_confuse_writers_10648.aspx#):

> syllabus (should be syllabi, not syllabuses)
>
> radius (should be radii, not radiuses)
>
> diagnosis (should be diagnoses, not diagnosises)

Interestingly enough, the spellchecker in my web browser only calls out "diagnosises" (which I don't think is actually a common mistake) as "not a real word".  The implication there being that over time "syllabuses" and "radiuses" have at least become common enough in use that the spellchecker will accept them.

Comment: *Syllabuses* is perfectly standard.  See [Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2684) for some interesting discussion on that subject.

Comment: @WendiKidd: Actually antennae and antennas are **both** valid plurals of antenna. The Latinate plural is more popular, but both are valid (http://grammarist.com/usage/antennae-antennas/)